# Install custom system image from network server

Tags: system-installation, pxe, foreman

I have a bootable image (ISO) of an Ubuntu system, but it is *not* an installer in itself.

I'd like to be able to instruct a system to copy the ISO over the network and effectively `dd` it to internal storage (overwriting anything previously stored there), and then reboot to its local copy.

(I don't want to simply boot from the image over the network.)

What would I need to set up to achieve this? What would need to already be installed on the target system, e.g., GRUB?

My use case is that I'm developing an embedded system and am regenerating these images routinely. I want to be able to easily flash the onboard storage whenever I have a new version of my software. There is nothing that needs to persist.

I'm looking for something fairly turn-key. I don't need a complicated menu of bootable recovery images. Something I can deploy to a local server as a Docker container would be fantastic.

Comment: This is not the best idea. A system can't just dd its internal storage with another image. You can dd an image while running from a live USB, but it is unclear why grub is needed, as you've claimed the image is bootable.

Comment: @mikewhatever The use case here is that I'm developing an embedded system and am regenerating these images routinely. I want to be able to easily flash the onboard storage whenever I have a new update. There is nothing that needs to persist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other commenters pointed out I should look at PXE booting. I wrote [my own project](https://github.com/rgov/netinstall) to provide a PXE boot service on my network, and then figured out how to build [iPXE](https://ipxe.org), a UEFI bootloader that can run a custom script on boot, which could for instance boot an ISO file over the network, or start up Linux with `dd` as pid 1, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Quite sure others can come up with something more elegant but...

-Boot the target system into a ubuntu live cd/usb.
-Assigned an IP address.
-Identify the target drive ex) /dev/sdg
-I believe you need to create a root password on the live system.

On the source machine:
(ensure ssh is installed in the live system)
`sudo dd if=/home/source.iso bs=4M status=progress | ssh root@liveCDUSB_IPaddress "dd of=/dev/sdg bs=4M"`

**Or in the other direction** (where adding a root password on the live system would not be necessary)
Instead on the live system pull the iso over from the source
`sudo ssh user@source_ipaddress "dd if=/home/source.iso bs=4M" | dd of=/dev/sdg bs=4M status=progress`

suggest testing with a small file to ensure all the verbiage is correct first...

Comment: Thanks. This is a decent workaround, for instance I can keep a bootable USB stick available. I was hoping to go a little more sophisticated with a complete provisioning process over the network.

Comment: yeah this is pretty manual, sounds like you want more automation? I should have asked first about pxe booting? I didn't see the pxe tag . I myself find just dd'ing images/virtuals right to drives/partitions easier, so I thought you might be like-minded when you mentioned dd. Are you looking for a pxe booting tutorial or a something easier? or does pxe not suit your needs at all?  Correct me if i'm wrong, but it seems you just want the target to boot up and copy the raw image, rather than the image files available as a resource on the server like w/ kickstart and the target doing the install?

Comment: I am new to PXE / network booting generally. Yes, I essentially want the target to boot up to some minimal environment, copy bits from the network to its internal storage, and then reboot.

Comment: I am not sure how to PXE boot in that manner. The only PXE booting I ever did, was installing the OS via the PXE boot, not straight copying it(which i agree with you would be much more simplified). Are the target machines physical boxes or VMs? If they can be virtuals you have a few options. You can script copying VMs themselves rather than the iso. I see you mentioned docker? Have you looked at Vagrant? I believe you can customize "vagrant boxes". I played with ansible and needed test machines ON my laptop and the tutorial to set up 3 vagrant ubuntu boxes was pretty easy from what i remember.

Answer (score 1):

PXE is your solution since the device is on the network permanently (implied from your responses)
sorry can't comment as reputation insufficient until voted...